# C# MVC not calling correct action method when adding form action dynamically through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

First of all, please forgive me if this looks a silly question but I am not being able to solve this.

I have a MVC page with the following structure (not using `HTML.BeginForm`):

```
<form id="frmMiniSearch" method="post">
   ... search controls are here ...
   <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.VehicleCondition, Model.Condition, new {@class = "form-control",@required="true"}) %>
   <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     $("#VehicleCondition").bind("change", function(){
        $("#frmMiniSearch").attr("action", "/quick-search/used/honda/civic/1968-2018")
     });
   });
</script>
```

When the above JavaScript executes, I can see the form (`frmMiniSearch`) action changes to `/quick-search/used/honda/civic/1968-2018`. But when I click on the `Submit` button, rather than calling the right action method, it is calling some other.

The above URL pattern is set in my RouteConfig.cs file:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "VehicleMiniSearchResult",
   url: "quick-search/{cond}/{makeSlug}/{model}/{yearRange}",
   defaults: new { controller = "SearchResult", action = "VehicleQuickSearch", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

I also tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("submit").click(function( e ) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $("#frmMiniSearch").submit();
   });
});
```

Result is the same. Still calling wrong method.

What I am doing wrong? Any suggestion would save my life.

NB: If I want to use `Html.BeginForm` to call the right method, how do I call it using the route pattern (i.e. `quick-search/used/honda/civic/1968-2018`)? Something like:

```
<% using(Html.BeginForm, "Action", "Controller", <something here?>) {} %>
```

I tried `Html.BeginRouteForm` but that did not seem to work either.

Thank you for your suggestion.

EDIT:

Here are the routes in the order of they appear in RouteConfig.cs

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "VehicleSearchResult",
  url: "vehicles/search/",
  defaults: new { controller = "SearchResult", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
  name: "VehicleMiniSearchResult",
  url: "quick-search/{cond}/{makeSlug}/{model}/{yearRange}",
  defaults: new { controller = "SearchResult", action = "VehicleQuickSearch", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

As far as I know route order is something we need to keep in mind in Orchard CMS, but does this true for pure MVC applications as well?

By the way, when I type in the URL in browser directly the route (`quick-search/used/honda/civic/1968-2018`) works and I get the desired result. Then it is not calling another method. It is only happening when I am trying to submit the form via JS.

Comment: What is the _other_ method that its calling?

Comment: Also just tested this and it works fine. What is the signature of your POST method? And is that route definition the first in your route table?

Comment: The method it is supposed to call is `VehicleQuickSearch`, but it is calling `DealerSearch` inside the same controller.

Comment: What other route definitions do you have before that one?

Comment: Let me get that.

Comment: I have updated my question and added the routes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168080/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-subrata-sarkar).

Answer (score 0):

This is not the accurate solution, its just a suggestion.

Why can't you use static action and pass the parameter in query string or in body?
in that way you can avoid dynamic uris.

or call the uri from the javascript function as

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("submit").click(function( e ) {
      e.preventDefault();
      //$("#frmMiniSearch").submit();
      //Call your uri here like window.location="";

   });
});
```

Comment: `window.location=""` is making a GET, not a POST (this has nothing to do with the question)